# How to read Mapinfo .tab file in SharpMap?

Tags: tab, sharpmap

I am using SharpMap Version 1.2.0.0.
I am able to read and export as a image of shapefile by below code.

```
        Map myMap = new Map(new Size(800, 600));           
        SharpMap.Session.Instance.SetCoordinateSystemServices(
           new CoordinateSystemServices(
                   new CoordinateSystemFactory(),
                   new CoordinateTransformationFactory(),
                   SpatialReference.GetAllReferenceSystems()));      

        VectorLayer myLayer = new VectorLayer("My layer");
        myLayer.DataSource = new ShapeFile(shapefilePath, true);

        //myLayer.CoordinateTransformation = Wgs84ToGoogle;
        // Add the layer to the map
        myMap.Layers.Add(myLayer);

        // Zoom the map to the extent of the shapefile
        myMap.ZoomToExtents();
        myMap.BackColor = Color.White;

        // Render the map to an image
        System.Drawing.Image mapImage = myMap.GetMap();

        // Save the image to a file
        mapImage.Save(outputPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

In this code we have shapefile provider, now I want to do same thing for MapInfo .tab file.
There are no provider for MapInfo File.
Is that possible or do I need to go for other open source.